# Error inflating TextInputLayout.Outlined after switching to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

Error inflating class `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` after switching to AndroidX and enabling `style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`

Hello friends,
today I switched my projects to Androidx (required for a new lib I need), and I get errors about my `TextInputLayout`.

Please note that it compiles perfectly when I remove OulinedBox style, but I absolutely need it for this project.

Does anyone knows a way to make OulinedBox TextInputLayout style work with AndroidX ?

Thank you so much for your help and time.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/gradient_begin_purple">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/login"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, I am facing this problem and couldn't solve it yet. Have you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this problem. I tried all things that given from stackoverflow but unfortunately couldn't find any solution. At the end I found the points that i missed.
(I assume that you put material design dependency in your build.gradle)

1)Your app them must be like followings(in values and values-21 folders)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

2)set activity theme to AppTheme in your `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Thanks changing     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 to     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"> worked for me. i.e replacing AppCompat to MaterialComponents.

Answer (score 2):

Add `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02"`
in place of support design library.
It is working perfectly for me after replacing above.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help, but I already had this in my build.gradle. I found a fix by removing this exact line, and replacing it with `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`, just like I had before moving to AndroidX. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get an error because you mix the support design library with the material components library.

Replace `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` with `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Drawable Resources which is missing in drawable-v21 thats why its crashing when you debug on lower version from 23

[image: See Missing resource]
[image: Show Error]